# Ask user to pick a cell in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a vba script that when a cell has been selected - $A$53 for example - I right click and select a macro on my command bar.

When the macro fires, I want to ask the user to select a cell using the mouse - say $F$66 - and returns the address to the macro.

Any hints please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox Have a go and post back if stuck showing your code. Then use the .Address property of the selected range.

Comment: Qharr. Thanks for the tip. I did as you said and it worked perfectly. I went to post my code on this post but Gary's student got there first. You answered my question for me and thank you.

Comment: Means you understand it well now! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function Pick_a_Cell() As String
    Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set r = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a cell", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If r Is Nothing Then
        Pick_a_Cell = "Cancelled"
    Else
        Pick_a_Cell = r.Address
    End If
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    x = Pick_a_Cell()
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```